# Getting rid of an old Facebook page with a lost password

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a Facebook page that was created for our business, but no one knows who created it or the password/email associated with it. We'd like to remove it or close it. However, I've tried everything I can find in the "Help" area and all of it leads me around in circles while getting *nothing* accomplished. What can I do?